# Logging Elastic Beanstalk Node Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, logging, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a node app running on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Logs are stored in S3. The logs I care about (right now) are custom error logs my app produces. What is the best practice that can pull these logs and display them in a readable manner? This can involve a 3rd party service or open source software.

Bonus question :-), I would like to integrate logs from my Rails API as well.

I would appreciate it if answers could include a few pros and cons of the service they recommend.

Comment: Asking for product recommendation is off-topic for StackOverflow. And there is no "best" - that is, it's opinion. So, no single right answer.

Comment: David, I changed the language a little as per your comment. However, people ask for gems, packages, libraries all the time, I don't think this is any different. Furthermore, "best" is not necessarily an opinion. The best runner in the Olympics is a very objective fact :-). Anyway, I asked that people list pros and cons also, to make it even more factual. Finally, logging is a huge part of coding, and its a pity I can't find the answer I am looking for on stack.

Comment: "Best" is subjective. You can't say objectively who the best runner in the Olympics is, but you can say objectively who the _fastest_ is for any particular race. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, the way to store & read logs, attach metrics and alarms on them etc. is to use CloudWatch Logs. I've done it and it's not bad. I liked working with graylog, but I'd have to send the data out of the cloud or run an instance with graylog, both options are suboptimal for me right now.

You actually have to run a command that enables the local logs agent on the instance, which can be done in the templates, but it's a bit awkward. I've created [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30798917/a-sane-way-to-set-up-cloudwatch-logs-awslogs-agent) (see the link for doc there), maybe someone knows a better way.